# django form rendering

Tags: django, forms

I have built a django form, simple extract as follows:

```
attachuploadediso = forms.BooleanField(label='Attach uploaded ISO', required=False)
detachuploadediso = forms.BooleanField(label='Detach uploaded ISO', required=False)
extractuploadediso = forms.BooleanField(label='Extract uploaded ISO', required=False)
```

I then render the form in my template as follows:

```
{% block mainbody %}
<form class = "mf" action="/form/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.label_tag }} {{ form.as_p  }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The checkboxes appear after the label text. Is there a way that check boxes appear in a line so the form looks likes better formatted? Or is there a way I can control the layout of the form better? I have used a form.as_table, but my jquery breaks if I render the form in a table.

So in short, I would like

(label) Attach uploaded ISO.............................(Checkbox)

(label) Detach uploaded ISO............................(Checkbox)

(label) Extract uploaded ISO.............................(Checkbox)

How can I control the layout better when a form gets rendered so the checkboxes are all in a line?

Thanks - Oli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render each field separately in the form and control look and feel. Each field has label which can be rendered as `{{field.label_tag}}` and field input as `{{field}}`.

More details from [Django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but because of my jquery I am running on my page, which I am initially hiding fields which aren't required until checkboxes are checked, great big white spaces appear.

Comment: @Oli That might be some different issue. May be you can verify the layout without making fields visible by JS.

Comment: ok thanks - your answer has given me something to work with.. i'll keep playing with it. Out of interest, is doing this a good idea? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template or should i try to let django do the rendering for me?

Comment: @Oli Generally, I use separate label and field rendering in template. But it depends upon actual layout and look & feel of a page.